# error: could not compile `time` when using cargo to compile

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Today when I run `cargo build` with my project in Fedora 32, shows compile error like this:

```
   Compiling devise v0.3.1
thread 'rustc' panicked at 'assertion failed: sentinel == STR_SENTINEL', /rustc/0b42deaccc2cbe17a68067aa5fdb76104369e1fd/compiler/rustc_serialize/src/opaque.rs:669:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

error: internal compiler error: unexpected panic

note: the compiler unexpectedly panicked. this is a bug.

note: we would appreciate a bug report: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new?labels=C-bug%2C+I-ICE%2C+T-compiler&template=ice.md

note: rustc 1.59.0-nightly (0b42deacc 2021-12-09) running on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

note: compiler flags: -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --crate-type lib

note: some of the compiler flags provided by cargo are hidden

query stack during panic:
end of query stack
   Compiling async-stream v0.3.2
error: could not compile `time`
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

my cargo version is:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/rust_wheel% cargo version
cargo 1.58.0-nightly (40dc28175 2021-12-06)
```

anybody facing the same problem? any fix suggestion? I searching from Google seem no one facing this same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this internal compiler error is tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91663):

> Try cleaning your build artifacts: `cargo clean`, in most cases the crash should go away after a rebuild.
>
> should be fixed with nightly `2021-12-11`